# Woocommerce Recently Viewed Products Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I want to include in my website the " Recently Viewed Produdcts" widget. I found out that i can do that with a shortcode as mentioned here: http://www.wpexplorer.com/woocommerce-recently-viewed-products-shortcode/

After implementing this code and creation of plugin the products appear in homepage very weird, very big and without any styling. Then i found out that there is already a widget in the widget section provided by woocomerce already.

I am very satisfied with the styling of it but i have some questions that i want to fix:

1. How do i add the widget to appear on all page just before the footer area?
2. How do i make that widget horizontal instead of vertical?

Thanks to whoever help me out !!!

Comment: Can you please post a link to the page that is in question? I would need to see it.

Comment: Sure. So here is the link with the widget : http://bigplanetcy.net/cart/ . If you noticed is in the cart page. The widget area i added it is the general sidebar widget. What i want though is to make it horizontall, and visible to the bottom of home page ( above footer) and i dont want it on any sidebar. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to insert the following into your footer.php file before the other div boxes start:

```
<div>
    <?php
    echo do_shortcode("[woocommerce_recently_viewed_products per_page='5']");
    ?>
</div>
```

Then we'll have to see what the styling looks like once that is in place.

Comment: I added what you said but everything (image related) below the Big Banner became huge. The sliders dissappeared and every image was huge. what else can we do?

Answer (score 1):

First, install the plugin "Recently Viewed Products Shortcode"

then:

```
<div><?php echo do_shortcode("[woocommerce_recently_viewed_products per_page='5']"); ?></div>
```

'5' instead "5"

Comment: By using the above plugin i can able to show recently viewed product in my local machine, But when i activated same plugin in my shared hostinger site it doesn't show any product instead it shows "You have not viewed any product yet!" why this happening please suggest any other way in live site